# React JS Modal Show White Blank Screen

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a data called **person** in JSON format getting from API in the file **User.js**:

```
  const [person, setPerson] = useState([]);
  const url = "http://localhost:8080/api/persons";
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(url).then((response) => {
      setPerson(response.data);
    });
  }, [url]);
```

In another file called **UpdatePersonForm.js** I'm trying to show that data in popup windows after clicking a button.

```
export const UpdatePersonForm= ({ person, personEditOnSubmit }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {person.map((item) => (
        <tr>
          <td>{item.name}</td>
        </tr>
      ))}
   </div>
```

}

then it shows a white blank screen again. If I called an API directly from **UpdatePersonForm.js** then it works fine. For example:

```
export const UpdatePersonForm= ({ personEditOnSubmit }) => {

 const [person, setPerson] = useState([]);
  const url = "http://localhost:8080/api/persons";
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(url).then((response) => {
      setPerson(response.data);
    });
  }, [url]);
  return (
    <div>
      {person.map((item) => (
        <tr>
          <td>{item.name}</td>
        </tr>
      ))}
   </div>
```

}

However, if I get data from the parent file like the above then I got wrong.

Comment: Please post the code of how you declare and how you set the `person`. Most likely `person` is undefined and the code crashes when you try to run `.map` on it.  Try declaring it `useState([])` instead of `useState()`

Comment: I just updated the code

Comment: does the `http://localhost:8080/api/persons` return an array ? please post the actual response structure from a call to that url.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli it returns an JSON format like that one I dynamically declared above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initialize the `person` variable with `const [person, setPerson] = useState("");` which means that on first render `person` will be a string and strings do not have a `.map` method.

Use `const [person, setPerson] = useState([]);` and you should be fine.

Since you expect it to be an array after the JSON is fetched, you should also initialize it to one.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your help so far. I got into another problem when getting data from parent file. I just updated the question. Can you take a look please?